# How to get number of items in a dataframe for each unique value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

One of the columns in the Dataframe is `STANME` (State name).  I want to create a pandas series with index = `STNAME` and value = number of entries in DataFrame.  E.g of sample output is shown below

```
STNAME
Michigan           83
Arizona            15
Wisconsin          72
Montana            56
North Carolina    100
Utah               29
New Jersey         21
Wyoming            23
```

My current solution is the following, but seems a but clumsy due to the need to pick arbitrary column, rename this column etc.  Would like to know if there is a better way to do this

```
grouped=df.groupby('STNAME')
# Note: County is an arbitrary column name I picked from the dataframe
grouped_df = grouped['COUNTY'].agg(np.size)
grouped_df.columns = ['Num Counties']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `value_counts()`. This function is used to get a `pd.Series` containing counts of unique values:

```
freq = df['STANME'].value_counts()
```

The index will be STANME, and the value will be it's frequency (first element is the most frequently-occurring element).

Note that NA's will be excluded by default.